# Performing a Kruskal-Wallis test on a data-frame

Tags: r

I have the following data-frame in R:

```
            lightmedians darksmedians
Dermaptera             4            2
Oniscidea             11            5
Diptera                6            5
Lepidoptera            2            1
```

I want to carry out a Kruskal-Wallis test (as the values are medians), to determine whether there is a significant difference between `lightmedians` and `darkmedians`.

I have tried `kruskal.test`, but the result gives a P value greater than 0.05 which does not seem to correct to me as the darkmedians column is lower for each order on the left-hand column.

Is R reading my data incorrectly, or am I using the wrong code for a Kruskal-Wallis test? Thanks.

Comment: My inital guess would be to take the raw values rather than median values of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you take the right statistical approach?
What are your groups, Insect families or Light versus Dark or are they actually both groups. You need a Two-way test and not a One-way test.

Rethink your statistical setup, this has nothing to do with R but about picking the right test for the experiment.

Comment: The aim is to determine whether the abundance of each insect family is affected by light. So I want to see if there is any statistical difference between the light treatment and the dark treatment.